# Is there a package to display topic values in rviz?

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my application several values are being published on ROS topics, they are mainly booleans, integers and floats, they could be ROS durations too for example.

I would like a Qt panel that would allow me to pick which topics should be displayed and that would display an LCD showing the value (dynamically) for each topic selected. This GUI must be easy to use (no command line etc.).

Did someone already develop something similar?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283388/is-there-a-package-to-display-topic-values-in-rviz?/) by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1505 on 2018-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I did not found a package doing the job, I made one called [topics_rviz_plugin](https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/topics_rviz_plugin) :

[image: https://gitlab.com/InstitutMaupertuis/topics_rviz_plugin/raw/kinetic/documentation/pick_topics.png]

The user clicks on configure, choose the topics he wants to be displayed (hovering the mouse will display the topic type in a tooltip).

[image: image description]

The topics are updated to display the last message available; this might not suit applications with high update rates as it will probably make values hard to read; this suits my needs.

Merge requests and issues are welcome to improve this package!

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2018-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VivosLespagnos](https://answers.ros.org/users/43194/vivoslespagnos/) on 2019-07-03**:
Hello,
I'm Vivien and i started the ROS code there is 1 month ago, so i try to do my best but sometimes it's always vagueness. (And i'm working on kinetic and not Melodic)

So i download you'r pkg, i did some little modification to have my own configuration and then i compile and all work. Anyway when i put in my launch file for an application a don't suceed to display the windows of topics. I don't know what i have to put in argument because i don't understand all the code. So if u know how to use and what writte in my main launch to call the fonction , it's can be cool for me.

thk lot if u see and anwsered.
sorry for english, im french hahah

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I think you can check the rqt plugin Topic monitor : http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_topic

Or you can try building your own RViz panel plugin to display exactly what you want : http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/rviz_plugin_tutorials/html/panel_plugin_tutorial.html

---

Originally posted by [Nico__](https://answers.ros.org/users/27606/nico__/) with karma: 36 on 2018-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-02-28**:
This does not integrate to RViz but it's a useful module.
I'll build my own RViz panel then